# Issue hiding worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

```
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name <> "Login" Then WS.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
```

I got error from the second line...

> Runtime Error 1004 : Application-defined or Object-defined Error

Comment: A rule: There has to be at least one sheet that is visible in a workbook. Try `If StrComp(WS.Name, "Login", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then WS.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden`.

Comment: The error is because you are hiding the last visible sheet, and hiding ALL the worksheets is not allowed.

Comment: Also test this for me. Add one line before the For loop. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Visible = xlSheetVisible. Now run the code and tell me if you are still getting the error? If No, then what @VBasic2008 mentioned above is the reason. If Yes, then we will have to investigate it a little more...

Comment: Had to delete and put a new comment as in the previous comment the `IF YES/IF NO` were swapped by mistake.